# Cant obtain USER on jsp - java Spring JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

The code in Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/loginForm")
public String getLoginForm() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/login")
public String login(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    return userService.getUserByLogin(user.getLogin()) != null ? "redirect:/" : "login";
}
```

Code on jsp, I cant see nothing

[image: my view]

But I can see other `<c>` tags on this page.
Thanks.

Comment: *Code on jsp, I cant see nothing....But I can see other <c> tags on this page.* What, exactly, can and can't you see on the page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to use the expression language syntax in your if-blocks:

```
<c:if test="empty user">
  This doesn't work
</c:if>

<c:if test="${empty user}">
  This should be rendered if user is null
</c:if>
```